# Negative axis in a log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, axis-labels

I'm plotting a log plot using matplotlib. My values go from 1 to 35.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.75, right=0.9)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', color='black', ls='')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

I would like to set the x- and y-axis starting from values lower than 1, but if I use

```
ax.axis([-10,45,-10,45])
```

it doesn't work. I know that it is because I'm using a log scale, but is there a way to solve the problem obtaining the axis I want?

Comment: @tcaswell I actually believe that OP wants to have axes with _negative_ values, as it is specified that the values to be plotted are ranging from 1 to 35, as well as the title of the post. With axis-limits at `[1e-10, 1e45, 1e-10, 1e45]` this data will be _very_ hard to represent in any informative way, as the limits are several orders of magnitude larger than the actual data.

Comment: @nordev ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `'symlog'` argument for [`ax.set_xscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale), as this is linear in a small interval around zero and logarithmic elsewhere.

You can even set the interval where you want the axis to be linear with the keyword argument `linthreshx` (`linthreshy` for `ax.set_yscale`), which accepts a tuple consisting of the limit on the negative and the positive side respectively, i.e. `linthreshx=(-linthresh,linthresh)`, or simply `linthreshx=linthresh`.

```
ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.axis([-10,45,-10,45])
```