# How to make an affine transformation of a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Using matplotlib.pyplot, I would like to make an affine transformation of a subplot.

Here is my use case:
1. I want to plot two subplots on the same row,
2. I want to add some text below the subplots (not using xticks or xlabels, but something like plt.text)
3. I need the text to be inside the figsize limit, i.e. the coordinates of the text must be between 0 and width/height.

My issue with my current code is that the subplots starts at 0 for the y-axis, which means that I print my text with negative coordinates for that axis. With the tool I'm using (Sphinx), it crops the plot and everything that is below 0 or above height is not displayed.

Here is a little example of what I'm doing right now. This doesn't work (some part of the text is not displayed).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(np.arange(10), 'o')
plt.xticks([], [])
for i in range(10):
    plt.text(i , - 1 + (i - 10) / 4, str(i), fontsize=17, color='C0')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 12), 'o')
plt.xticks([], [])
for i in range(10):
    plt.text(i, 1 + (i - 10) / 4, str(i + 2), fontsize=17, color='C0')

plt.show()
```

I would like to limit the plots to a range of heights, for instance (1, 3), so that I could display the text with a positive coordinate. Obviously, if it can be done with another solution, I'd take it.

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Check this link, if this gives you an idea.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872026/negative-axis-in-a-log-plot

Comment: You can specify a transform to a text object: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/text_alignment.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies! [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) did the trick.

Comment: @johann.faouzi I am glad, you found the answer. Please answer the question, so that it can help someone too. :D

Answer (score 0):

[matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) did the trick: the whole text can be seen when the image is saved.

See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642082/text-or-legend-cut-from-matplotlib-figure-on-savefig).